# New path is not reflected in Python code

Tags: python, directory

I have a code in which I am loading a text file from a folder. The code looks like this:

```
snap1 = np.loadtxt("../data/milli_17")
snap2 = np.loadtxt("../data/milli_19")
```

So the milli17 and milli19 files are located in a folder that is located in the same folder with my working folder. So far everything was good. However, I moved the data folder inside the working directory so the directory placement became like this: /Workingdirectory/data/

So I went ahead and reflected that on the code by removing the two dots so it wouldn't go up one directory:

```
snap1 = np.loadtxt("/data/milli_17")
snap2 = np.loadtxt("/data/milli_19")
```

However now when I run the code I get an error saying the directory does not exist:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/milli_17'

but debugging shows the line of error as this:

> ----> 4     snap1 = np.loadtxt("/data/milli_17")

Couldn't get my head around it, all seemed OK to me. Where do I make the mistake?

Edit:
I don't think the problem has something to do with how I write down the path. The problem is that it doesn't matter what I put there, the code still (as seen in the error code) goes and checks the old directory.

Comment: give the path like this: np.loadtxt("./data/milli_17"); same for the other

Comment: Yep changed, but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restart the kernel that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the file extension and no forward slash before the data folder.

```
snap1 = np.loadtxt("data/milli_17.txt")
```

Comment: The text file itself does not have an extension. It is just milli_17. At first, I wrote the path without the slash and it didn't work either.